# как сделать загрузку шрифтов из fonts.googleapis.com после загрузки страницы?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700,900%7COpen+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i&amp;subset=cyrillic" rel="stylesheet">
```

чтобы при загрузке сразу не тормозило открытие сайта

Comment: Вы хотите невозможного. Чтобы страница считалась полностью загруженной — нужно отрисовать текст, а чтобы отрисовать текст — нужно загрузить все необходимые шрифты.

Comment: Грузите шрифт локально и подключайте из локального источника. Либо, если вам нужно скрыть недостатки страницы без шрифта, используйте прелоадер

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить только скачать шрифты и подключить локально. Также какой-нибудь старый `.ttf` можно конвертировать в `woff` или `woff2`. А вообще шрифты должны загружаться довольно быстро. Ну и шрифты типа `Roboto`, которые есть в ОС подключать не надо.

`Font Awesome` тоже можно [скачать](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/hosting-font-awesome-yourself). Далее надо будет просто выбрать нужный вам файл со стилями и перенести из архива папку со шрифтами на хостинг или локальный компьютер. Я обычно использую `all.min.scss`, но там также есть стили и для `less` и просто `css` и даже отдельные категории иконок. Если будете использовать отдельные категории шрифтов, вам надо будет также подключить `fontawesome.scss` вместе с файлом стилей категории.

Папка со шрифтами называется `webFonts`. Переносим ее и нужный файл стилей в проект, остальные папки и файлы можно удалить. Если Вам уж так хочется, можно также удалить из папки со шрифтами все `.ttf`, но они прям мало весят. Далее файл стилей подключаем к сайту до основного файла со стилями и пользуемся иконочными шрифтами.

Ну и конечно можно скачать отдельные иконки не как шрифт, а как картинки в формате `.svg` Они находятся в нашем архиве в папке `svgs` Оттуда можно взять всего пару необходимых иконок и не нагружать сайт шрифтами.

Comment: мне нужно просто задействовать fontawesome а он не хочет работать без шрифтов как сделать так чтобы минимальный набор был и локально?

Comment: @junior Дополнил ответ